# I am getting an unknown operand and cannot understand why

Tags: hard-drive

To the following command: sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/disk3 bs=1024 count 1024 I get unknown operand count. How can I overcome this?

Comment: Are you missing an `=` there? And could you please format code and output

Comment: the " "  (space) is a delimiter which separates options.  your `count=` has no value hence error, and 1024 is an operand option for `dd` I doubt is in `man` (manual page). the space between them means they [count & 1024] aren't related.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/disk3 bs=1024 count=1024
```

As derHugo wrote, there is a missing `=` at the end of the command.